Where do the streaming apps save their downloaded video files in Android Device?
I have an Online study app on my mobile. I have bought their Subscription and Downloaded their Classes. Now I can only avail those Classes through the app. But I want to save those Classes as mp4 files in my SD card.
Most apps save their Data in this location-> "Internal Storage/Android/Data", but when I open this folder, I can't find any Subfolder of that app. Where does it save it's data? If I can find them, can I turn them into mp4 files?
